# Doit-on favoriser l'usage du passif en français ?

Tags: passif, style-de-rédaction

Dans les rédactions de documents en langue anglaise, on m'a toujours demandé d'utiliser la voie passive :

> The truth about what has been said earlier will be described in the next chapter.

En revanche, il semble que le français soit plus friand des formulation du style

> Nous verrons dans le prochain chapitre…
>
> Nous décrirons ensuite…

tournures de phrase que je pense l'anglais tolérerait moins.

Il y a-t-il des règles concernant ce type d'usage ? Est-ce que je devrais préférer l'une des formulations par rapport à l'autre ?

Comment: L'emploi de "we" dépend aussi du style. Par exemple, ddans l'écriture mathématique on l'utilise très, très souvent.

Comment: Tiens moi j'étais persuadé que c'était en anglais que l'usage du passif était à proscrire.

Comment: Tu veux dire: "L'usage du passif doit-il être favorisé en français" ?... ;-)

Comment: Plus sérieusement, je ne crois pas qu'il y ait de différence entre les langues: dans les deux cas il s'agit d'un choix stylistique. Le passif (en anglais comme en français), peut parfois s'apparenter à l'usage de "weasel words" pour donner un ton impersonnel qui n'est pas toujours désirable. Mais l'usage de  "we"/"one" est à peu près aussi courant que "nous"/"on" dans un texte de type académique (ce qui semble être le cas de tes exemples).

Comment: Ta première phrase (en anglais) me semble très lourde. Si je la voyais, j'aurais tendance à supposer que l'auteur n'était pas anglophone. C'est peut-être une différence entre l'américain et le britannique? La mode semble commencer à tourner contre Strunk et White, mais ils sont fortement contre le passif, et leur livre a été la bible de la grammaire américaine au moins depuis les années 60. Orwell aussi proscrit l'usage du passif.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La voix active est souvent préférée à la voix passive en français, contrairement à l'anglais, dans certaines situations. [Le guide du rédacteur](http://www.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-srch?lang=fra&srchtxt=passive&cur=1&nmbr=2&lettr=&page=) du Bureau de la traduction du gouvernement du Canada contient au moins deux articles à ce sujet :

> Dans la mesure du possible, il est conseillé d’avoir recours à la voix active, la voix passive impliquant l’usage d’articles, d’adjectifs et de participes propres à la forme masculine et à la forme féminine. L’emploi de la forme active permet d’éviter toute ambiguïté ou d’éliminer l’effet de répétition :
>
> - Nous vous prions de…
>               *au lieu de*
>          Vous êtes priés et priées de…
>
> - Si vous ne pouvez assister à la réunion…
>               *au lieu de*
>          Si vous ne pouvez être présent ou présente à la réunion…

Et

> En français, la voix active est généralement plus naturelle que la voix passive. Les phrases à la forme active sont souvent plus faciles à comprendre parce qu’on voit tout de suite qui fait l’action. Au lieu d’écrire :
>
> > L’entreposage des transformateurs et la pose des bennes suspendues *doivent être pris en charge* par l’entrepreneur.
>
> on peut très bien rétablir l’actif, pour souligner le rôle de l’agent :
>
> > L’entrepreneur *doit prendre en charge* l’entreposage des transformateurs et la pose des bennes suspendues.
>
> Il ne s’agit pas ici de frapper d’interdit la construction passive, qui est parfaitement admise en français et qui permet de donner un éclairage différent. On peut très bien dire
>
> > Le courrier *est expédié* tous les jours à la même heure par la secrétaire du directeur.
>
> *ou*
>
> > La secrétaire du directeur *expédie* le courrier tous les jours à la même heure.